# Using URL Rewrite in IIS as Reverse Proxy

Tags: proxy, iis, reverse-proxy, url-rewriting, xforwarding

I am running a IIS server acting as a reverse proxy using URL ReWrite.  It is being set up to forward https web requests as http to a web server inside our network.  It appears to be forwarding correctly, but it is not sending the x-forwarded proto header and the software team is saying that they need that header to come across.  Please see my configuration below, any help is greatly appreciated.

[Config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koLfY.png)

[Config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOslv.png)

[Wireshark1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9waRR.png)